# Robust way to parse text content from HTML in PHP?

Tags: php, html-parsing

I'm trying to find a robust way to parse ALL of the text (i.e. non-html/non-code/non-script content) from an HTML document.  I'm talking specifically about extracting keywords on any input web page on the internet.  I'm writing a keyword spider that tracks keyword trends on web pages using PHP, and although I've found a number of great ways to actually read in the content (like DOMDocument and cURL), I'm having a hard time finding any robust solutions for actually parsing out *all* of the word content separate from the HTML/Javascript/CSS/etc on any old random page on the Internet.

I first tried using strip_tags(), but it has lots of artifacts of javascript and other xml that might be on the page.  I've also tried [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), but it seems to have problems with punctuation and whitespace handling.  I finally tried building a library from tutorials on [nadeausoftware](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/php_tip_how_extract_keywords_web_page), and while it works phenomenally well on most pages, on some pages it doesn't return any content at all (I guess the curse of trying to use regex for parsing).

I'm just wondering if there aren't any php libraries that provide the specific capability of grabbing all of the non-html/non-javascript/non-xml/non-code *words* from an HTML document.  I know that might sound like a tall order, and I'm not looking for perfection, but if there's a solution that's 80% reliable on most web-pages, I'd be happy.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the PHP parsing code from [nadeau software](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/php_tip_how_extract_keywords_web_page) is actually more robust than I originally gave it credit --- on additional tinkering, I discovered that the problems I was encountering were due to my feeding the parser html content that wasn't properly encoded to utf-8.

It's unfortunate that there don't seem to be any existing libraries for handling such a complex use-case, but at least I was able to get the tutorial code to work on a broad number of test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the document, get rid of the tags you don't want and then query the `textContent` property:

```
$html = '<html><head><style type="text/css">hola</style></head><body><script>tada</script><a href="#">hello <span>world</span></a></body></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node) {
    if (in_array($node->nodeName, array('script', 'style'))) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
echo $dom->documentElement->textContent;
// hello world
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/r5N3hdt2)